# How to make a hybrid model (LSTM and Ensemble) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, lstm, prediction, hybrid

I am working on C02 prediction in matlab. My data set is 3787 (Including test and validation set). I am trying to predict the CO2 with a Standard Deviation of 179.60. My number of predictor is 15 and response is 1. Within that predictors I have two types of datasets (1. Sequential number data such as temperature and humidity, 2. Conditions i.e yes/no ). So that I have decided to use two types of networks to train my model.
1) LSTM - For the sequential data
2) Ensemble or SVM - for the yes/no data 
3) Combine two models and predict the response variable.
How to achieve this? Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to use machine learning algorithms, there is no reason why to use two different approaches and join them later. They actually benefit from the correlations between different data sources, that we as humans are unaware of. They also don't care about mixed-integer problems =) (BTW, you can use SVM also for regression)

Comment: quick side question: what do you mean with *ensemble*? Particle methods?